# Windows Form Desktop application Log out

Tags: c#, winforms

On start of my Application `Login Form` comes up I have simply stored username and password and compared for validating user, if user is valid than `MDIparent Form` gets opened, Now I want to create `logout` for this Application. How I can do this?

When I searched I Found That I can do this on FormClosing Event or FormClosed Event but what code should be written in that and for which form, only `Dispose();` is enough or something more?

What if I want `Login Form` to get displayed back?

**Showing MDI Form after Successful Login Like this**

```
private void login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {   
            //if password true then send true           
            bool value = namePasswordEntry(getHashedUserName, txtUserName.Text, getHashedPassword, txtPassword.Text);
            if (value ==true)
            {                
                MessageBox.Show("Thank you for activation!");
                this.Hide();
                Form2 pfrm = new Form2(txtUserName.Text);
                pfrm.ShowDialog();    
            }

            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid LoginName or Password..");
            }       
        }
```

Comment: It will automatically logged out when you will close the form. What do you want when your form is closing?

Comment: After closing I want to open `Login Form` again ,should i simply write their `LoginForm.show()` ?

Comment: just paste the code how are you showing the MDI form after succesfull login

Comment: @Shaharyar Added Code for how I am showing the MDI form after succesfull login

Comment: Show your main method, How you're showing login form?

Comment: Form2 is my Login Form

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following codes in the form closing event

**Application.Exit()**; - Informs all message pumps that they must terminate, and then closes all application windows after the messages have been processed.

**System.Environment.Exit(1)**; - Terminates this process and gives the underlying operating system the specified exit code.

**Application.Restart()** - Shuts down the application and starts a new instance immediately.

Source : http://msdn.microsoft.com/

Answer (score 1):

You Should try this on cancel button or your form closing event........................... `Application.Exit();`

Comment: How can I merge `closing event` in `Linklabel click event`?

Comment: This will close the whole application. OP doesn't want this

Answer (score 0):

```
if (value ==true)
        {                
            MessageBox.Show("Thank you for activation!");
            this.Hide();
            Form2 pfrm = new Form2(txtUserName.Text);
            pfrm.ShowDialog(); 
            pfrom.Dispose(); //because user has logged out so the data must be flushed, by "Disposing" it will not be in the RAM anymore, so your hanging problem will be solved
            this.Show(); //just add this line here   
        }
```

To **Logout** using `Link Label` you just need to raise the `click` event of it. Write this code in the `Form2` constructor:

```
linkLabel1.Click += linkLabel1_Click;
```

and then create a method:

```
void linkLabel1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
```

Comment: what will happen using this ,and what about Logout link?

Comment: It will show your `login` form after closing the `MDI` form. and what do you want as `logout`? I could not understand that part

Comment: i am using `Link label` for `Logout` how I can make this workout if I use closing event? or how do I use these? How control will come to this line `this.Show();`

Comment: So you want to close the form using this `link label`? not by `X` icon of the form?

Comment: I doing it first time ,I don't know how it can b done using icon,anything will work for me as far as it logs out

Comment: In windows form programing, there is no session like web.However, you can store your login data(authenticated) in static variables. Check those static variables on form load of the form which required authentication. When user clicks logout link, set null or empty those static variables and load the login form or exit the application. Hope this help.

Comment: Yes It closes Form ,but while showing `Login Form` back this form hangs I mean it get shown but not properly,may be because of its previous state?

Comment: @Durga No this not the issue. May be your `Form2` is too heavy. Thats why it is happening. I forgot something, I am adding it in answer. After that it will all be smooth and efficient :)

Answer (score 0):

If anyone still needs this solution:

```
private void logoutButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

   this.close();

}
```